# In TypeScript, can we create reusable interface for an array of functions?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have Vue + Typescript and am trying to figure if there's a better way to describe types for an array of functions. I currently have the following code. Could I define a `formRules` interface instead of re-declaring the types `Array<(v: string) => boolean | string>` or even just `<(v: string) => boolean | string>`?

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  name: 'signUpForm',
})

export default class SignUpForm extends Vue {
  private valid = true

  private firstName = ''
  private lastName = ''
  private nameRules: Array<(v: string) => boolean | string> = [
    (v) => !!v || 'Name is required',
  ]

  private email = ''
  private emailRules: Array<(v: string) => boolean | string> = [
    (v) => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
    (v) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
  ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a type that is equal to your function signature.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  name: 'signUpForm',
})

type FormFunction = (v: string) => boolean | string;

export default class SignUpForm extends Vue {
  private valid = true

  private firstName = ''
  private lastName = ''
  private nameRules: FormFunction[] = [
    (v) => !!v || 'Name is required',
  ]

  private email = ''
  private emailRules: FormFunction[]*emphasized text* = [
    (v) => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
    (v) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
  ]
}
</script>
```

As a side note, you should not have to specify the type at all as TypeScript is able to figure it out on its own. Just specify the type of the paramater v if Typescript doesn't know what it is:

```
export default class SignUpForm extends Vue {
  private valid = true

  private firstName = ''
  private lastName = ''
  private nameRules = [
    (v: string) => !!v || 'Name is required',
  ]

  private email = ''
  private emailRules = [
    (v: string) => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
    (v: string) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
  ]
}
```

That would be the cleanest way to do it, with the less unnecessary type definitions.

Comment: thanks!! selected this as the accepted answer as it also addresses `a better way to describe types`

Answer (score 2):

```js
type CheckFunc={(v:string):boolean|string}

type ArrCheckFunc=CheckFunc[]


let formRules:CheckFunc[]
//or
let formRules:ArrCheckFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example-

```
 type fArr = ((v:string)=>boolean | string)[];
 let x:fArr;
 x=[(v:string)=>v];
 x[0]("h");
```